# How to rotate this graph in graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have the following graph

[image]

The dot file I used to generate is:

```
strict graph G {
ratio=1;
0 -- 1;
0 -- 4;
1 -- 5;
1 -- 2;
2 -- 6;
2 -- 3;
3 -- 7;
4 -- 8;
4 -- 5;
5 -- 9;
5 -- 6;
6 -- 10;
6 -- 7;
7 -- 11;
8 -- 12;
8 -- 9;
9 -- 13;
9 -- 10;
10 -- 14;
10 -- 11;
11 -- 15;
12 -- 13;
13 -- 14;
14 -- 15;   
}
```

How do I force the output of the command `dot -Tpdf test.dot -o test.pdf` to be a square graph, instead of this diamond like shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by subgraph with `rank=same`

```
strict graph G {
    ratio=1;
    {0 1 2 3 rank=same}
    {4 5 6 7 rank=same}
    {8 9 10 11 rank=same}
    {12 13 14 15 rank=same}
    0 -- 1;
    0 -- 4;
    1 -- 5;
    1 -- 2;
    2 -- 6;
    2 -- 3;
    3 -- 7;
    4 -- 8;
    4 -- 5;
    5 -- 9;
    5 -- 6;
    6 -- 10;
    6 -- 7;
    7 -- 11;
    8 -- 12;
    8 -- 9;
    9 -- 13;
    9 -- 10;
    10 -- 14;
    10 -- 11;
    11 -- 15;
    12 -- 13;
    13 -- 14;
    14 -- 15;   
}
```